# sudo: unable to resolve host server1.yourdomain.com: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, squid

OS: Ubuntu 18.0.4

i install Squid with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install squid
```

after install i small change on squid.conf , only change this http_access deny all to http_access allow all

after save change i run this command

```
sudo service squid restart
```

but i get this error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host server1.yourdomain.com: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

and i check my hosts file , i see this text:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

i check my hostname file , i see this text:

```
server1.yourdomain.com
```

i change this text to ubuntu

after change i run again this command:

```
sudo service squid restart

and this command

sudo service squid stop
```

but i get again this error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host server1.yourdomain.com: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

and test this command:

```
sudo service squid reload
sudo: unable to resolve host server1.yourdomain.com: Resource temporarily unavailable
squid.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

i check ping ip , get good ping

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine tries to resolve server1.yourdomain.com but fails.

The first step of dns resolving is that the instance is looking in its own /etc/hosts file before checking the next dns server.

Simply edit the server's /etc/hosts file and change this line: `127.0.0.1 localhost` to:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost server1.yourdomain.com
```

Then restart squid service:

```
service squid restart
```

Comment: please check this problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/928482/squid-the-requested-url-could-not-be-retrieved